# Is USB extender/repeater needed for more than 16 ft cable to simply charge an iPad?

Tags: usb, cable, ipad

The power outlet where I charge my iPad is more than 16 ft away. I noticed there are two type of USB extension you can get, a regular one and a repeater/extender. Do I need a repeater/extender if I am just using this to charge my iPad and not for data?

Comment: What about just a standard power extension cord?

Comment: @ultrasawblade Yeah, that could work too, though it's more unwieldy I think compared to USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using a USB/Mains wall outlet?

[USB wall outlet](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/travelpower/e81a/)

I use one of  [these RCA USB](http://rcaaudiovideo.com/power/chargingstations/?sku=WP2UWR) as I can travel with it and use it at home as well

Links are for North America outlets

Comment: See my comment on Zach's, replacing my outlet with USB version won't help. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: -1 He said "The power outlet where I charge my iPad is more than 16 ft away"  That means he is already using one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to charge you should be fine, if you try to do any data transferring you may run into problems with signal loss.

Dave M's comment on getting a wall charger is spot on though.  Why run a 16ft cord just to charge something?

Comment: You are missing the point. The distance between the outlet and the iPad are more than 16 ft. Yes, I can move all the furnitures away, but that's besides the point. I can't move the outlet, replacing it with a USB version won't help. But thanks for the clarification on the charge vs data transfer. I guess I'll get the regular extension.

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing you can do, and doesn't involve worrying about that electronic issue, is get a Mains extender cord

[image]

Comment: If you were to not do that, and to try to extend the USB.. then it's very much a technical electronic issue,  like how far can 2 really thin wires(one 5V one GND) , from a USB cable, shielded, carry an electric signal. it may be 18 AWG..

Comment: ..  This link automatedbuildings.com/news/dec08/columns/… says be aware of how long your runs are, and upsize to the next larger gauge if need be, by using a voltage drop chart or graph. <-- I suppose after a certain distance you may get a voltage drop. So the wires may be too thin to cover the distance. The fact that USB is shielded helps with one aspect, but I suppose won't stop the voltage drop(if there is a voltage drop).   ANYHOW, that aside, as mentioned, the mains extension cord like one pictured, would solve it without a doubt no problem.